How to continue on the same fragment after applying dark theme?
I have created 4 different fragments in one activity. When the theme is applied in the app through setting fragment, the navigation of setting fragment is selected but the screen of HomeFragment is shown instead of setting fragment.
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_setting, container, false);

        // Night and Light Mode
        SharedPreferences preferences = requireContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean isNightMode = preferences.getBoolean(KEY_THEME, false);

        if (isNightMode) {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
        } else {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        }

        SwitchCompat switchDarkMode = view.findViewById(R.id.themeToggleButton);
        switchDarkMode.setChecked(isNightMode);

        switchDarkMode.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (getActivity() != null) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean(KEY_THEME, isChecked);

                    // Save the current fragment tag before the theme change
                    Fragment currentFragment = getParentFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
                    if (currentFragment != null) {
                        editor.putString("last_fragment_tag", currentFragment.getTag());
                    }
                    editor.apply();

                    // Set the theme and recreate activity
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(isChecked ? AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES : AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);

                    // Recreate the activity to apply the theme change
                    getActivity().recreate();
                }
            }
        });

when theme is applied the app should show continue(setting fragment).

how do you load fragments? using Navcontroller? if no please start doing it, it will save your state

Use a base fragment for all fragment and extends it from all fragment. In the base fragment add this code inside onCreateView
if (AppPreferences.INSTANCE.isDarkTheme())
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
        else
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);

let me know if you face any issue

I have already done it.

Are you still facing issue?
you have added it in fragment, instead create a base fragment and then do it

This way, after the theme is changed, the app will stay on the last fragment instead of going back to the home fragment.
// In your SettingFragment
SwitchCompat switchDarkMode = view.findViewById(R.id.themeToggleButton);
switchDarkMode.setChecked(isNightMode);

switchDarkMode.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean(KEY_THEME, isChecked);

            // Save the current fragment tag before the theme change
            Fragment currentFragment = getParentFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
            if (currentFragment != null) {
                editor.putString("last_fragment_tag", currentFragment.getTag());
            }
            editor.apply();

            // Set the theme and recreate activity
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(isChecked ? AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES : AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);

            // Recreate the activity to apply the theme change
            getActivity().recreate();
        }
    }
});

// In your Activity
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Restore the last fragment after theme change
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("your_preference_file", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String lastFragmentTag = preferences.getString("last_fragment_tag", null);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        if (lastFragmentTag != null) {
            // Restore the last selected fragment
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(lastFragmentTag);
            
            if (fragment != null) {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, lastFragmentTag)
                        .commit();
            }
        } else {
            // Load the default fragment (e.g., HomeFragment) if no fragment tag is saved
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new HomeFragment())
                .commit();
        }
    }
}


did what you told. The navigation of setting fragment is selected but the screen of HomeFragment is shown instead of setting fragment.
